# Show that if $f\in C([a,b])$ and $f(x_1)=1$ for some $x_1\in[a,b]$ then $f(T)\neq 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T:V\to V$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $V$. We know that its spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is contained in some finite interval $[a,b]$. We consider the ring homomorphism 
\begin{align*}
\varphi : &\Bbb{R}[X] \to \Bbb{R}[T]  \ \text{given by} \ f:=f(X) \mapsto f(T),
\end{align*}
where $\Bbb R[X]$ denotes the ring of all polynomial functions on $[a,b]$.
We also know that $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous with the sup-norm on $\Bbb{R} [X]$ and the operator-norm on $\Bbb {R}[T]$. So we can extend the map $\varphi$ to a continuous map
$$\overline{\varphi}:\overline{\Bbb{R}[X]}\to\overline{\Bbb{R}[T]},$$
where $\overline{\Bbb R[X]}$ is the sup-norm closure of $\Bbb{R}[X]$ in $C([a,b])$, and the latter is the operator-norm completion of $\Bbb{R}[T]$.
Note that by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, we have $\overline{\Bbb{R}[X]}=C([a,b])$ where $C([a,b])$ is the ring of real-valued continuous functions on $[a,b]$.

**My question 1.**: Show that if $f\in C([a,b])$ and $f(x_1)=1$ for some $x_1\in[a,b]$ then $f(T)\neq 0$.

**My question 2.**
Let $\tau(T)\subseteq[a,b]$ be the simultaneous zero-set of $\operatorname{Ker}(\overline{\varphi})$. How can we show that if $f\geq 0$ on $\tau(T)$ then $f(T)\geq 0$.

In fact, from the following notes

http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2016-17/spectral_theorem_bdd.pdf

we know that if $f\geq 0$ on $[a,b]$ then $f(T)\geq 0$ at the first page.

Comment: What if $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\sigma(T)$?

Comment: @Aweygan Then we have $x_1\notin \sigma(T)$ which implies that $T-x_1 I$ is bijective. I think I am missing some basic issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not true as you have written it. Consider $T=\Bbb1$, take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and look at $f(X)=1-X$. Clearly $f(0)=1$ but $f(T)=0$.

The statement can be modified to be true however:

> If $f\in C[a,b]$ and $f(x_1)\neq0$ for some $x_1\in\sigma(T)$, then $f(T)\neq0$.

If you know the Gelfand-Naimark theorem then the map $C([a,b])\to\Bbb C[T]$ factorises over
$$C[a,b]\to C(\sigma(T))\overset{\cong}\to \Bbb C[T]$$
and it is clear that $f$ is not sent to zero in the first map. If you don't know this theorem we can also do it on foot:

Let $p_n\to f$, $f(T)$ is defined as $\lim_n p_n(T)$. Since $f(x_1)\neq0$ we can assume |$p_n(x_1)|$ is always larger than some number $c$. Since
$$\sigma( p_n(T) )=\{ p_n(x)\mid x\in \sigma(T)\}$$
you have that
$$\|p_n(T)\|=\sup_{x\in \sigma(p_n(T))}|x|=\sup_{x\in\sigma(T)}|p_n(x)|≥c$$
it follows that $\lim_n p_n(T)$ cannot be $0$.